# Sqlite COUNT returns `[object Statement]`

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, better-sqlite3

I have `let usersin1 = sql.prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raid WHERE raid1 > 0");`

using better-sqlite3 and what I'm getting from this is a [object Statement]. I don't understand why I'm getting it when I try to get the value of usersin1. All values are defined and I'm trying to get a number out of this.

Node.js

Comment: A statement is just a representation of the actual database statement to be run. After that you need to run it - check here https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-statement
ie., should be something like `sql.prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raid WHERE raid1 > 0").get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sql.prepare()` returns a `Statement` object. You need to execute the statement to get the results.

```
let stmt = sql.prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM raid WHERE raid1 > 0");
let row = stmt.get();
let usersin1 = row.count;
```

Comment: If that's the case then why wouldn't something like 
`let usersin2 = sql.prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raid WHERE raid2 > 0").get().count;`

do the same thing

Comment: Yes, you could do that. It's just not as clear for explaining all the steps.

Comment: This may not work since there will be no `count` key on the `row` object. There will be `COUNT(*)` key though.
In order to simplify it and make your code work, the query should state `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM raid WHERE raid1 > 0`

Comment: @Kyeno I have the alias `count` in my SQL. The keyword `AS` is optional in SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can do : `let usersin1 = sql.prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raid WHERE raid1 > 0").get().count;`

Comment: There will be no `.count` key. Check my comment to the answer above.